# How to dynamic update 2 templates simultaneously in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

in the folowing jsFiddle i have add a little example ember application. In the 'details' view i want to display information about the selected group and if i click on a device in a group, i want to replace the details with the device details. How can i manage this in ember way?

http://jsfiddle.net/theremin/qGCe6/1/

**TEMPLATES**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h2>SampleApp</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="groups">

    <div>
        <h3>Groups</h3>             
<div style="">
            <ul>
            {{#each controller}}
                <li>{{#linkTo "devices" devices}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{render 'devices'}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{render 'details'}}
    </div>
</script>    

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="devices">

    <h3>Devices</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
        {{#each model}}
            <li>{{#linkTo "details" App.Device}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="details">
    <h3>Details for:</h3> 
    <div>
        <i>{{model}}</i>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision    : 12,
    adapter     : 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource('groups', function() {
        this.resource('devices', { path: "/:group_id" });
        this.resource('details', { path: "/:device_id" });
    });
});

/**
 * ROUTES
 */
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('groups');
    }
});

App.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model       :   function( ){
        //console.log("--->", App.Group.find());
        return App.Group.find();
    }
});

/*App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
        return this.modelFor("details");
    }
});*/

/**
 * MODELS
 */
App.Group = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    details: DS.attr('string'),
    devices: DS.hasMany('App.Device')
});

App.Device = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    details: DS.attr('string'),
    groups: DS.hasMany('App.Group')
});

/**
 * FIXTURES
 */

App.Group.FIXTURES = [{
    id:1,
    name:"Group one",
    details:"details for Group one",
    devices:[1,2]

},{
    id:2,
    name:"Group two",
    details:"details for Group two",
    devices:[2]
}];

App.Device.FIXTURES = [{
    id:1,
    name:"Device1",
    details:"details for Device1",
    groups: [1]

},{
    id:2,
    name:"Device2",
    details:"details for Device2",
    groups:[2]
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qGCe6/4/) what you wanted to acheive ?

**Changes Made**

I've changed the nesting

```
App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource('groups', function() {
        this.resource('devices', { path: "/:group_id" }, function(){
            this.resource('details', { path: "/:device_id" });
        });
    });
});
```

So that the routes would be something like `/groups/:group_id/:device_id`

Then I've removed the `{{render}}` helpers & added `{{outlet}}` in the templates

Changes in `devices` template, I am passing the `device` model to the controller, you were passing `App.Detail`

```
{{#each device in model}}
    <li>{{#linkTo "details" device}}{{device.name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Changes in `details` template

Now that we have the entire model we can get the details using the `details` property

```
<i>{{model.details}}</i>
```

If you think I did not interpret your question properly, let me know, I'll update the answer accordingly

**Update as per the comments:**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVBRd/2/)

#### Only one detail(Final Solution)

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVBRd/3/)

The changes required are

removing the `{{template}}` which was displaying group details & using a single `{{outlet}}` for both details.

adding redirection in `GroupIndexRoute` which redirects to display group details on clicking a group

```
App.GroupIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    var model = this.controllerFor('group').get('model');
    this.transitionTo('detail',model);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The fiddle works fine. But it is not exactly  what i need. I have done some rework on the fiddle. May you have a look on it? The feature i want to learn is something like apples  finder. http://jsfiddle.net/theremin/UVBRd/

Comment: ignore previous comment which I deleted, posting another one

Comment: You Click a Group & two views should be displayed one is a list of devices along with group description, right ? and what if when someone clicks on a device ?

Comment: when someone click on a device i want to display device specific informations. if someone click on a group i want to display all devices containing to the group and specific informations about the group.

Comment: i see ... the middle columns headline in my last fiddle should be 'Devices' not 'Group'.

Comment: See the fiddle at the end in the updated answer, If you've got doubts let me know I'll explain them in the answer

Comment: Hi unspecified ;) thank you for your toil ... i have to catch up much stuff learning ember.

Comment: If the fiddle was exactly what you've been looking for then you can accept the answer by clicking the Tick Mark next to it :)

Comment: Is there a solution only to show one details - view. For example: The User clicks on a group - the groups details will be shown. The User select a device only(!) the device details will be displayed ?

Comment: See the fiddle inside "Only one detail" section & let me know if this is what you have been looking for